# Quit Application on Escape button pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently making a simple 2D Pong game in Unity for a school project, and I have this code attached to my camera so that when the exit key is pressed it will close it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EscapeScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("escape"))
        {
            Application.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

However whenever I'm in it, pressing Escape does absolutely nothing. I have tried variations such as "GetKeyDown" and "KeyCode.Escape" but they don't seem to work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out. It was because I was in the editor, and Application.Quit() doesn't work while in the editor. I needed to use UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;

Comment: Careful though! Remember to also exclude anything related to the `UnityEditor` namespace from your build via preprocessor tags `#if UNITY_EDITOR`! Otherwise you'll get compiler errors when you try to build your app